# Why can't I use "strong" or "assign" here? I'm programming in MVC mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to make a picker view, and I have a plist filled with names of countries. Now I want to load these data through my Model and display them on the picker view with my Controller. At first I used "assign" and "strong " to describe the property "name" in the file "WXFlagsModel", but once I started to scroll the picker the program just crashed! Then I tried "copy" and then every thing works just fine. Can someone please tell me why？Thanks everybody!
1.this is the part of "WXFlagsModel.h"file

```
        #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WXFlagsModel : NSObject

@property (copy ,nonatomic) NSString *name;

@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *icon;

-(instancetype)initWithDict:(NSDictionary*)dict;

+(instancetype)flagsWithDict:(NSDictionary*)dict;

+(NSArray*)flags;

@end
```

2.view controller

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "WXFlagsModel.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *flags;
@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - lazy loading
-(NSArray *)flags
{
    if (_flags == nil) {
        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"flags.plist" ofType:nil]];
        
        NSMutableArray *arrayM = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
            WXFlagsModel *model = [WXFlagsModel flagsWithDict:dict];
            
            [arrayM addObject:model];
        }
        _flags = arrayM;
    }
    return _flags;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    NSLog(@"%@",self.flags);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - picker view delegate

#pragma mark - picker view data source
// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.flags.count;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
//    WXFlagsModel *flag = [WXFlagsModel new];
    WXFlagsModel *flag = self.flags[row];
    return flag.name;
}


#pragma  mark - private methods

@end
```

3.And here is the line where bug happens.

```
return flag.name;
```

and Xcode tells me this:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address = 0x20)

PS:I'm not allowed to embed in screen shot here, so I just typed words instead.

Comment: `assign` is used for primitive types. `strong` is used for objective c class types.

Comment: give details of the crash, include the exception name, message and stack trace

Comment: I'd place a bet that it's not the return statement that crashes. Any warnings in your code?